# Constructing ECPublicKey from ANSI X9.62 encoded bytes

Tags: java, cryptography, ecdsa

I need to validate the signature generated remotely, by ECDSA secp256k1 curve. I get 64 bytes, representing the raw bytes of r and s. And the ANSI X9.62 encoded public key (`[0x04, X (32 bytes), Y (32 bytes)]`). How can I verify the signature using this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already have x and y as BigIntegers:

```
// Create the W point
ECPoint w = new ECPoint(x, y);

// Create the ECField from hey integer (p)
ECField field = new ECFieldFp(new BigInteger("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F", 16));

// Create the EllipticCurve with a and b
EllipticCurve curve = new EllipticCurve(field, new BigInteger("0"), new BigInteger("7"));

// Create the G point:
BigInteger gx = new BigInteger("79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798", 16);
    BigInteger gy = new BigInteger("483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8", 16);
ECPoint g = new ECPoint(gx, gy);

// Create ECParameterSpec
ECParameterSpec spec = new ECParameterSpec(curve, new ECPoint(gx, gy), new BigInteger("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141", 16), 1);

// Create the KeySpec:
KeySpec keySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(w, spec);

// Generate the key
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
PublicKey key = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

The constants used here are available [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1)

Answer (score 0):

This code is decoding the plain text form from the curve's point byte array and checks a signature:

```java
// extract the key with known domain parameters
            ECGenParameterSpec ecGenParameterSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");
            AlgorithmParameters algorithmParameters = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("EC");
            algorithmParameters.init(ecGenParameterSpec);
            ECParameterSpec ecParameterSpec = algorithmParameters.getParameterSpec(ECParameterSpec.class);
            ECPoint point = ECPointUtil.decodePoint(ecParameterSpec.getCurve(), pubKey);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
            ECPublicKeySpec ecPublicKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(point, ecParameterSpec);
            ECPublicKey ecPublicKey = (ECPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(ecPublicKeySpec);

// verify the signature, here using SHA256
            Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
            signature.initVerify(ecPublicKey);
            signature.update(data);
            boolean valid = signature.verify(receivedSignature));
```

`ECPointUtil` is coming from BouncyCastle, but it is also possible to parse it. Skip the first `04` from the encoding and then convert the next 32 bytes with `BigInteger` to the x and y coordinate.